# Laravel 5.2 web middleware group in routes.php is gone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I recently starte a new laravel project and realised the web middleware group in the routes.php is gone.

It still seems to use it though - therfore I'd like to ask where it is configured since it is not listed in the Kernel.php as default middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \GeneaLabs\LaravelCaffeine\Http\Middleware\LaravelCaffeineDripMiddleware::class,
];
```

I'm actually asking because I want to create an additinal api to my app and therefore I'd like to **not** use the web middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer my self. The root of this behaviour is in the **RouteServiceProvider** where the map function applies the middleware.

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: This gave me a headache for some hours sometime before. I really don't like this decision.

Comment: I actually somehow rememberd that it was presented in a laracast, but didn't remember where :) - I pretty much like it since you cleanup your routes.php and now simply create something like routes-api.php and reference it in the mapWebRoutes. No need to mix api Routes with app routes in one file

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking? On the default `Kernel.php` these are still there:

```
    /**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Then in your `routes` even the default `web` is not there, then put it.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']],function(){
      //your routes ...
});
```

Or if you do not want the session in your api endpoint:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']],function(){
      //your routes ...
});
```

Comment: I cannot verify this. I do not have a Route::group middleware in my routes.php but still get TokenMismatchException if I do add my token - therefore it seems as web middleware is attached without actually attachnig it

Comment: Ofcourse I do have the web middleware defined in my Kernel - that's not the problem, but it's not defined in the default middleware that is called every request - therefore i wonder why it's still used

Comment: Yes there is no route group by default in routes.php that is why you need to add the middlewares as to your liking. If you do not need the Sessions etc, just append the middleware "api" value and your good!

Comment: Still cannot agree to this - please refer to my given answer. The web middleware ist implictly applied in the RouteServiceProvider

Comment: Starting with Laravel 5.2.27, the web middleware group is applied automatically. You do not need it in your routes file anymore. The framework applies it behind the scenes